# Jacobian derivation of 2 variables of Secant method

Tags: discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods

When dealing with 2 independent variables in vector systems :

$f_1(x,y)$ and $f_2(x,y)$, vector $F=(f_1,f_2)$ and vector $X=(x,y)$,one can derive the numerical iteration from the Newton method:

$X^{n+1}=X^{n}-J^{-1} F^{n}$ where $J = \pmatrix{df_1/dx&df_1/dy\\df_2/dx&df_2/dy}$ is the Jacobian

My question is: How to derive the same iteration expression with the Secant method? What is the expression of the Jacobian?

Comment: [Broyden's method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%27s_method) is a multivariable generalization of the secant method. Is that what you're interested in?